# Can't get notebloc to let me type in my text appropriately

Tags: javascript, html, react-native

I'm new in react native, and I'm building a notebloc. The problem now is that I want to allow the user to write in color, to do that the component has a method called `insertHTML`, the problem here is that each time I execute the insertHTML, it inserts the element but can't write inside of it until I write `&nbsp;` example:

`<span> &nbsp; </span>`

the problem is if I have two string of different colors together, if I hit spacebar from the first string and the backspace and spacebar again, the second string that is stuck to it takes the color of the first string. Here I'm going to paste a screen that shows in the console step by step the structure of the notebloc:

[image]

As you can see, the second hola at the beginning was red, one it's stuck to the first hola, it's `&nbsp;` is deleted and if I go to the beginning of the first hola and hit spacebar, there's a `&nbsp;` then backspace it's deleted and when I hit spacebar again, the second hola that was red become blue and both come inside a `<font>` tag, why is this happening? and how can avoid it?

Comment: I've made some edits to your question, mostly the title, since it wasn't describing the question well at all, but also trying to split up the text into sentences. You could probably do a better job on that last one, because I lost the train of thought. Also, code should be include as text, not as pictures of text, so please copy and paste the HTML from that console as text.

Comment: please read how ask (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)